# Angular-carousel is not working

Tags: angularjs

```
<div>
    <carousel interval="myInterval">
        <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
            <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;width: 200px;height: 200px;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
            </div>
        </slide>
    </carousel>
</div>

    $scope.myInterval = 5000;
    var slides = $scope.slides = [];
    slides.push({image: 'img/css1.png', text: '亲爱的你，情人节快乐'});
    slides.push({image: 'img/css2.png', text: '亲爱的你，情人节快乐'});
    slides.push({image: 'img/css3.png', text: '亲爱的你，情人节快乐'});
    slides.push({image: 'img/css4.png', text: '亲爱的你，情人节快乐'});
    slides.push({image: 'img/css5.png', text: '亲爱的你，情人节快乐'});
    slides.push({image: 'img/css6.png', text: '亲爱的你，情人节快乐'});
```

I 'm trying to make a demo of carsousel. 
I just follow the code as the link.[enter link description here](http://www.cnblogs.com/ilovewindy/p/3777831.html)And the images are just listed on the view.it confused me.i don't know what else should i do?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Plz show your code. And you can see the error message  on the DevTools console.

Comment: the link http://www.cnblogs.com/ilovewindy/p/3777831.html

Comment: I think the sample on the site is not complete.
You can see the official sample code [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel)

Comment: I made a simple sample [here](https://jsbin.com/gobugequji/1/edit?html,js,output).